# apache2 on ubuntu webserver rejects permission to access any other file than the delivered index.html

Tags: linux, permissions, webserver, apache2

I am trying to set up a webserver running on Ubuntu. I have installed Apache and changed the root directory to an other directory within /var/www/. When I copy the index.html provided by Apache to that directory, I can access that file via remote webbrowser. But if I want to use a different index.html file, even really basic ones, I get an error: "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource". I have also tried to download that html, alter just a few lines and put it back on to the server with the result that it also shows that error. If I rename the initially provided index.html to index2.html I can still access it. I do not understand how it is possible that only this exact file is working.

I have tried to grant more permissions with Directory and restarted Apache but it won't work. I am rather new to Linux and Apache, can only use the terminal on my webserver and I do not know what else to do. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the permissions on the file, too, not just the folder. Pretty sure this fix it.

For diagnostic correction, allow permission for all by typing:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/index.html
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you. What is the normal way to grant these permissions?

Comment: This should be fine, as you do it on a file-basis. Please mark my answer as a solution (tick), since it solved it, so others know it's solved. Thank you.